# vue-i18n single file component in laravel project

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-mix, vue-i18n

Given a Laravel 5.5 project, I want to use the "**single file component**" of the vue-i18n plugin. [Documentation](http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/en/sfc.html). It seems simple, but I can't get it to work.

**app.js**

```
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
Vue.use(VueI18n)
const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    messages:     {
        "en": {
            "word1": "hello world!"
        }
    }
})
Vue.component('test', require('./components/test.vue'));
const app = new Vue({ i18n, el: '#apps'});
```

**components/test.vue**

```
<template>
    {{ $t('word1') }}
    {{ $t('word2') }}
</template>

<i18n>
    {
    "en": {
    "word2": "does this work?"
    }
    }
</i18n>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "test"

        data() {
            return {
                locale: 'en'
            }
        },

        mounted() {},

        watch: {
            locale (val) {
                this.$i18n.locale = val
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

word1 is being replaced, however word2 is not. Placing bad syntax between the i18n-tags in the vue file, does NOT result in an error while compiling the files (`npm run dev`). This makes sense, because I'm missing the:

[Taken from the documentation](http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/en/sfc.html)

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
     ...
```

This is supposed to go in the `Webpack configuration`. But, where is this file in laravel? All I can find is the webpack.mix.js, but placing this code in there, does not do much... Also making it `mix.module.exports` does not do the trick. Searching led me to [this topic](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/732), but i'm not sure if he's asking the same as I am.

**The problem:** the i18n-tags aren't loaded. The solution is to add the code from the documentation.

**My question:** Where do I add this code?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone stumbling upon the same problem, I proposed a change in the documentation:
https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/pull/237

Laravel mix has its own rules for .vue files. To add the `vue-i18n-loader`, add the following to **webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.webpackConfig({
// ...
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            // Rules are copied from laravel-mix@1.5.1 /src/builder/webpack-rules.js and manually merged with the ia8n-loader. Make sure to update the rules to the latest found in webpack-rules.js
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader',
            exclude: /bower_components/,
            options: {
                // extractCSS: Config.extractVueStyles,
                loaders: Config.extractVueStyles ? {
                    js: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: Config.babel()
                    },

                    scss: vueExtractPlugin.extract({
                        use: 'css-loader!sass-loader',
                        fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
                    }),

                    sass: vueExtractPlugin.extract({
                        use: 'css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax',
                        fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
                    }),

                    css: vueExtractPlugin.extract({
                        use: 'css-loader',
                        fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
                    }),

                    stylus: vueExtractPlugin.extract({
                        use: 'css-loader!stylus-loader?paths[]=node_modules',
                        fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
                    }),

                    less: vueExtractPlugin.extract({
                        use: 'css-loader!less-loader',
                        fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
                    }),

                    i18n: '@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader',
                } : {
                    js: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: Config.babel()
                    },

                    i18n: '@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader',
                },
                postcss: Config.postCss,
                preLoaders: Config.vue.preLoaders,
                postLoaders: Config.vue.postLoaders,
                esModule: Config.vue.esModule
            }
        },
        // ...
    ]
},
// ...
});
```